# UITabbar item image is not shown properly

Tags: ios

UITabbar item's image tint color is grey(default) when the view appear for the first time before user select one tab.

Screen shot when the view appear for the first time:

[image: screen shot when the view appear for the first time]

Comment: all of your tabbar images are grey?

Comment: No only the unselected one,but after user select one tab its working perfect

Comment: Can you post screen shots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and I solved by inserting the `UITabBar item` with this code:

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBarController.tabBar;
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem1 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem2 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
    UITabBarItem *tabBarItem3 = [tabBar.items objectAtIndex:2];

    tabBarItem1.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tabBarItem2.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    tabBarItem3.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img3.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

    tabBarItem1.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1_sel.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

I added this code to all my view controller (in my case 3) and it create the right image, while selected and not selected. I hope it helps you